# Batching multiple files to Amazon S3 using the Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to upload multiple files to Amazon S3 all under the same key, by appending the files. I have a list of file names and want to upload/append the files in that order. I am pretty much exactly following [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html) but I am looping through each file first and uploading that in part. Because the files are on hdfs (the Path is actually org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path), I am using the input stream to send the file data. Some pseudocode is below (I am commenting the blocks that are word for word from the tutorial):

```
// Create a list of UploadPartResponse objects. You get one of these for
// each part upload.
List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();

// Step 1: Initialize.
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(
        bk.getBucket(), bk.getKey());
InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse =
        s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
try {
      int i = 1; // part number
      for (String file : files) {
        Path filePath = new Path(file);

        // Get the input stream and content length
        long contentLength = fss.get(branch).getFileStatus(filePath).getLen();
        InputStream is = fss.get(branch).open(filePath);

        long filePosition = 0;
        while (filePosition < contentLength) {
            // create request
            //upload part and add response to our list
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Step 3: Complete.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new
          CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bk.getBucket(),
          bk.getKey(),
          initResponse.getUploadId(),
          partETags);

    s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
} catch (Exception e) {
      //...
}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 2C1126E838F65BB9), S3 Extended Request ID: QmpybmrqepaNtTVxWRM1g2w/fYW+8DPrDwUEK1XeorNKtnUKbnJeVM6qmeNcrPwc
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1109)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:461)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:296)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3743)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.completeMultipartUpload(AmazonS3Client.java:2617)
```

If anyone knows what the cause of this error might be, that would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively, if there is a better way to concatenate a bunch of files into one s3 key, that would be great as well. I tried using java's builtin [SequenceInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) but that did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. For reference, the total size of all the files could be as large as 10-15 gb.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably a bit late but worth giving my contribution.
I've managed to solve a similar problem using the `SequenceInputStream`.

The tricks is in being able to calculate the total size of the result file and then feeding the `SequenceInputStream` with an `Enumeration<InputStream>`.

Here's some example code that might help:

```
public void combineFiles() {
    List<String> files = getFiles();
    long totalFileSize = files.stream()
                               .map(this::getContentLength)
                               .reduce(0L, (f, s) -> f + s);

    try {
        try (InputStream partialFile = new SequenceInputStream(getInputStreamEnumeration(files))) {
            ObjectMetadata resultFileMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            resultFileMetadata.setContentLength(totalFileSize);
            s3Client.putObject("bucketName", "resultFilePath", partialFile, resultFileMetadata);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("An error occurred while combining files. {}", e);
    }
}

private Enumeration<? extends InputStream> getInputStreamEnumeration(List<String> files) {
    return new Enumeration<InputStream>() {
        private Iterator<String> fileNamesIterator = files.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return fileNamesIterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream nextElement() {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(Paths.get(fileNamesIterator.next()).toFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

Hope this helps!