# Is there a way to batch upload a collection of InputStreams to Amazon S3 using the Java SDK?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I am aware of the `TransferManager` and the `.uploadFileList()` and `.uploadFileDirectory()` methods, however they accept `java.io.File` types as arguments. I have a collection of byte array input streams containing jpeg image data. I don't want to create in-memory files to store this data before I upload it either.

So what I need is essentially what the S3 client's `PutObjectRequest` does but for a collection of `InputStream` objects. Also, if one upload fails, I want to abort the whole thing and not upload anything, much like how a database transaction will reverse the changes if something goes wrong along the way.

Is this possible with the Java SDK?

Comment: The sdk doesnt seem to provide such methods as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

Before I share an answer, please consider upgrading...

> #### fyi - `TransferManager` is `deprecated`, now supported as `TransferManagerBuilder` in JAVA AWS SDK, please consider *upgrading* if [`TransferManagerBuilder`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManagerBuilder.html#withS3Client-com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3-) Object suits your needs.

---

now since you asked about `TransferManager`, you could either **1)** copy the code below and replace the functionality/arguments with your custom in memory handling of the input stream and handle it in your custom function... or; **2)** further below is another sample, try to use this as-is...

---

1. Github source modify with with [inputstream](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2f88b992a03902970ba595044eb593a736c47b61/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/event/ProgressListener.java#L104-L111) and [issue listed here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2059)

```
private def uploadFile(is: InputStream, s3ObjectName: String, metadata: ObjectMetadata) = {
    try {
      val putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3ObjectName,
        is, metadata)
      // TransferManager supports asynchronous uploads and downloads
      val upload = transferManager.upload(putObjectRequest)
      upload.addProgressListener(ExceptionReporter.wrap(UploadProgressListener(putObjectRequest)))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
  }
```

---

2. Bonus, Nice custom answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476155/batching-multiple-files-to-amazon-s3-using-the-java-sdk) using `sequence input streams`

```
public void combineFiles() {
    List<String> files = getFiles();
    long totalFileSize = files.stream()
                               .map(this::getContentLength)
                               .reduce(0L, (f, s) -> f + s);

    try {
        try (InputStream partialFile = new SequenceInputStream(getInputStreamEnumeration(files))) {
            ObjectMetadata resultFileMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            resultFileMetadata.setContentLength(totalFileSize);
            s3Client.putObject("bucketName", "resultFilePath", partialFile, resultFileMetadata);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("An error occurred while combining files. {}", e);
    }
}

private Enumeration<? extends InputStream> getInputStreamEnumeration(List<String> files) {
    return new Enumeration<InputStream>() {
        private Iterator<String> fileNamesIterator = files.iterator();

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return fileNamesIterator.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream nextElement() {
            try {
                return new FileInputStream(Paths.get(fileNamesIterator.next()).toFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    };
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the answer and taking the time to write that out but it's not really what I asked. I have a collection of ByteArrayInputStreams and I need a more efficient way to batch upload them without creating multiple `.putObject()` requests. Also, the second answer isn't as relevant either as I mentioned I don't want to load the files in memory before the upload which your code seems to rely on.

Comment: Afaik I don't think the SDK provides a way to do this though.